# ¿Como Obtener la Fecha de Inicio y Final de una Semana teniendo el numero de la semana?

Tags: c#

Tengo el numero de la semana, quiero obtener la fecha que comprende esa semana:

Ejemplo:
La semana comienza el día lunes (primer día), y finaliza el domingo

- Semana 1 de 2018 = 01/01/2018 - 07/01/2018
- Semana 52 de 2018 = 24/12/2018 - 30/12/2018
- Semana 1 de 2019 = 31/12/2018 - 06/01/2019

Comment: No creo que alguien programe eso por ti, deberías subir el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 2):

Hay que trabajar varios tipos de aspectos para generar esta oración en base a una fecha.

```
string setRangoSemana(DateTime fecha)
        {
            var noSemana = numeroSemana(fecha);
            //Validación para verificar si es la ultima semana del anio
            var semana = primerDíaSemana(noSemana == 52 ? fecha.AddYears(-1).Year : fecha.Year, noSemana, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            var lunes = semana.AddDays(1);
            var domingo = semana.AddDays(7);
            return string.Format("Semana {0} de {1} = {2}-{3}", noSemana, fecha.Year, lunes.ToShortDateString(), domingo.ToShortDateString());
        }
```

Teniendo el numero de semana **numeroSemana()** pasare a obtener el primer día **primerDíaSemana()** en base al año y el número de la semana este te retorna el primer día de la semana, en este caso domingo.

```
int numeroSemana(DateTime time)
    {
        DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
        if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            time = time.AddDays(3);
        }
        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    }
static DateTime primerDíaSemana(int year, int weekOfYear, System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci)
        {
            DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
            int daysOffset = (int)ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - (int)jan1.DayOfWeek;
            DateTime firstWeekDay = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
            int firstWeek = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
            if ((firstWeek <= 1 || firstWeek >= 52) && daysOffset >= -3)
            {
                weekOfYear -= 1;
            }
            return firstWeekDay.AddDays(weekOfYear * 7);
        }
```

Y el resto de días los sumas con la función **AddDays()**

Answer (score 0):

Debido a tu poca investigación, te colocaré esta [RESPUESTA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19901870/8933039) del usuario [@Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) en base a una pregunta similar realizada en **SO en Inglés**.

**Traducción explicita** (Respuesta Original) :

> Puede usar los dos métodos siguientes para calcular el número de semana y la fecha de inicio de un número de semana determinado de acuerdo con un año determinado:

```
// este método es tomado de http://stackoverflow.com/a/11155102/284240
public static int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
{
    DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
    if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        time = time.AddDays(3);
    }

    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
} 

public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(int year, int weekOfYear, System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci)
{
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    int daysOffset = (int)ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - (int)jan1.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime firstWeekDay = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
    int firstWeek = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    if ((firstWeek <= 1 || firstWeek >= 52) && daysOffset >= -3)
    {
        weekOfYear -= 1;
    }
    return firstWeekDay.AddDays(weekOfYear * 7);
}
```

> Entonces puede obtener ambas fechas de la siguiente manera:

```
// 46
int thisWeekNumber = GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Today); 
// 11/11/2013  
DateTime firstDayOfWeek= FirstDateOfWeek(2013, thisWeekNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
// 11/12/2012  
DateTime firstDayOfLastYearWeek = FirstDateOfWeek(2012, thisWeekNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

> Agregue 6 días para llegar al final de la semana.

El código no se ve complicado y es fácil de entender esto debería ayudarte.

Saludos.!